# Radius of Convergence of Complex Power Seies

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

For a complex power series
$$P(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...,$$
$P(z)$ converges if 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}z|=|z|\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1.$$
The radius of convergence $R$ is defined by
$${1\over R}=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|.$$
If we show this radius of convergence on an Argand diagram by drawing a circle of radius R with centre at the origin, $P(z)$ is convergent for $z$ values lying inside the circle.For $z$ values lying outside the circle, $P(z)$ diverges. ***For $z$ values lying on the circle, the series may converge or diverge.***

My question is why can the series converge for $z$ values lying on the circle? I know that for a geometric series in the form of $a+ar+ar^2+...$ the series can only converge for $|r|<1$. For z values lying on the circle, it is analogous to saying that $|r|=1$ so the series should not converge.

Edit: I came across this on a textbook and had posted a screenshot of it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBc1w.png).

Comment: Recall that in real analysis, $\ln 2=1-\frac12+\frac13\pm\ldots$, which is the Taylor serieso of $\ln(1+z)$, with convergence radius $1$, evaluated at $x=1$.

Comment: Consider $a_n = 1/n^2$. Then the series is absolutely convergent everywhere on the circle.

Comment: You're correct that the radius of convergence of $a+ar + ar^2 + \dots$ is $|r|<1$ and this diverges for every complex $r$ with $|r|=1$.  However, the $a_n$'s in $P(z)$ are allowed to be different numbers, whereas for the first series they were all just $a$...